# can public game for Android use Unity Personal

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm just starting to work with Unity engine and I want to know

```
1. Unity free version has the ability to publishing game on Google Play Store?
```

2. What are the limitations of the free version (Unity Personal)?

Thanks.

Comment: here is a good read : [Unity Personal vs Unity Plus vs Unity Pro vs Enterprise](https://ironic.games/coding-games/unity-personal-vs-unity-plus-vs-unity-pro-vs-enterprise)

Comment: [I downvoted because research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/). Unity provides all the elements needed to answer this questions by yourself. [Compare plans](https://store.unity.com/), [Knowledge base](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us), [FAQ](https://unity3d.com/unity/faq)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The public, free version has virtually all the functionality that the paid version has.

To answer your questions:

- Yes, unity free can publish on google play
- The limitations are mainly on Support from the Unity Company. Also you get a discount in the assetstore with the paid versions. 
  You **need** a paid version if you earn more than $100.000 a year. 
  I believe there may be an extended profiler with the paid version, but I'm not sure.

Also, the free version forces the Unity logo on your splash screen (initial loading screen) on publish builds. You can remove this by purchasing the paid version.